# Binding a video in Datalist ASP .NET C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, video, upload

I am a new .NET developer and using Visual Studio 2010 with c# language. 
I have a problem to upload and retrieve videos in my web site. I am using eval by path to upload photos and retrieve it into database.
Here is the HTML source :

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        Width="962px">
        <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("news_image")%>'  Height="200px" Width="300px" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
```

and here is the code behind to insert image into db:

```
 if (FileUpnewsimg.HasFile)
            {
                str = FileUpnewsimg.FileName;
                FileUpnewsimg.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(".") + "../images/Uploaded Images/" + str);
                string patth = "/$AdminPanel$/images/Uploaded Images/";
                path = patth + str.ToString();
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    con.Close();
                }
                con.ConnectionString = conn.connction();
                con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into web_content (news_head,news_content_par1,news_content_par2,news_content_par3,news_content_par4,news_image,news_image_binary) values ('" + txttitle.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + txtsection1.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + txtsection2.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + txtsection3.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + txtsection4.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "','" + path + "','" + FileUpnewsimg.FileContent + "')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                Response.Redirect("News-Admin.aspx");
            }
```

I want to upload video into database using the same way.
Anyone can help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

In DataList

```
     <ItemTemplate>
    <u>
        <%# Eval("Name") %></u>
    <hr />
    <a class="player" style="height: 300px; width: 300px; display: block" href='<%# Eval("Id","           "FileCS.ashx?Id={0}") %>'>
    </a>
</ItemTemplate>
```

1)Add JS

```
  <script src="FlowPlayer/flowplayer-3.2.12.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   flowplayer("a.player", "FlowPlayer/flowplayer-3.2.16.swf", {
    plugins: {
        pseudo: { url: "FlowPlayer/flowplayer.pseudostreaming-3.2.12.swf" }
    },
    clip: { provider: 'pseudo', autoPlay: false},
    });
 </script>
```

2)On Click of Upload Code Behind

```
    protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

     using (BinaryReader reader= new BinaryReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
     {
      byte[] bytes = reader.ReadBytes((int)FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Length);
      // Add Here your sql query and give upload path
      }
     and on your page load Bind the DataList
```

3) Use Generic Handler for live streaming Video files from Database

Comment: Always shows this error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve by  configuring AppPoolidentity  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/friis/archive/2012/09/19/c-compiler-or-visual-basic-net-compilers-fail-with-error-code-1073741502-when-generating-assemblies-for-your-asp-net-site.aspx